# Create shell script file to change brightness values of xrandr

Tags: bash, xrandr

How can i create shell script file to change `xrandr` brightness by increasing or decreasing its value by **0.1**?

I'm using this command in konsole to change value of brightness:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness .7
```

where i can change **.7** value between **1** to **0**.

so any suggestion ,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the same problem once and have written a little script to do just what you are asking for.

GitHub: [xrandr-brightness-script](https://github.com/philippnormann/xrandr-brightness-script)

It basically just calls `xrandr --current --verbose` and uses `grep` to extract the current brightness value.

Then it adds or subtracts 0.1 to that value and calls the command you described.